# apply a function over all combination of tensor rows in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to make a function `f1(arg_tensor)` which gets a pytorch tensor as an argument.

In this function I use another function:
`f2(tensor_row_1, tensor_row_2)` which gets two pytorch's tensor rows as an arguments and outputs a scalar.

`f2(..)` should be applied over all combinations of tensor's rows `[1..n]` (i.e. apply function `f2(..)` on tensor rows' indices: `[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]...[0,n-1]...[n-1,0]..[n-1,n-1]`).

The output of `f1(..)` should be a tensor such that at element `[0,0]` there will the output value of `f2(tensor_rows[0], tensor_rows[0])` and so on...

Is there a way to perform it efficiently (and not with double `for` loop)?

Comment: @iacob f2 is ```KLDIVLOSS```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one can do it with a simple broadcasting trick:

```
def f1(tensor):
    tensor = tensor.permute(1, 0)
    return torch.nn.functional.kl_div(
        tensor.unsqueeze(dim=2), tensor.unsqueeze(dim=1), reduction="none"
    ).mean(dim=0)


def manual_f1(tensor):
    result = []
    for row1 in tensor:
        for row2 in tensor:
            result.append(torch.nn.functional.kl_div(row1, row2))
    return torch.stack(result).reshape(tensor.shape[0], -1)


data = torch.randn(5, 7)

result = f1(data)
manual_result = manual_f1(data)

print(torch.all(result == manual_result).item())
```

Please notice, for more rows the result will differ **due to numerical difference**. You can:

- `print` the values and inspect manually
- use `torch.isclose` to verify similarity

In the second case, last `print` would become:

```
print(torch.all(torch.isclose(result, manual_result)).item())
```