# Apply a generic function to an all-to-all couple of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a question [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741628/apply-a-function-over-all-combination-of-tensor-rows-in-pytorch), using a **generic function** of the kind:

```
def f(a, b):
   return Something
```

This something can be a scalar, or a tensor. The application of `f` should be all-to-all from the rows of two matrices **that are possibly aliased** like:

```
def apply_very_slow(source1, source2):
    s = torch.tensor(...) # compute the right dimensions
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(k):
            p = f(source1[i], source2[j])
            s[i,j] = p
```

Of course this is immensely slow. I could be calling `apply_very_slow` with the same argument `apply_very_slow(M, M)` or different tensors `apply_very_slow(M, N)`, but I have no guarantee that in this case `M` and `N` point at the same data.

Moreover, I'd like the results to be autograd-friendly. No problem if `f` must be converted to a class. In the questions I've linked they use `torch.nn.functional.kl_div`, but I need a solution to be generic.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to apply `f` in an [*outer* fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), ie. of the form `i,j->ij`. You can do so with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by unsqueezing dimensions on both inputs:

```
>>> M = torch.rand(10, 3)
>>> N = torch.rand(5, 3)
```

Here are some example functions applied ([`F.kl_div`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.kl_div.html), [`F.l1_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.l1_loss.html), and [`F.pairwise_distance`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pairwise_distance.html?highlight=pairwise_distance#torch.nn.functional.pairwise_distance)):

```
 >>> y = F.kl_div(M[:,None], N[None], reduction='none')
 # shape of (10, 5, 3) last dim not reduced

 >>> y = F.l1_loss(M[:,None], N[None], reduction='none')
 # shape of (10, 5, 3) last dim not reduced

 >>> torch.pairwise_distance(M[:,None], N[None])
 # shape of (10, 5) last dim reduced
```